# React Native reload flatlist each time user hits the API

Tags: react-native

```
React, {useCallback, useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  
} from 'react-native';
import Nodata from '../main/banking/common/Nodata';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
import axios from 'axios';
import useSessionToken from '../hooks/useSessionToken';
import moment from 'moment';
import ListData from '../main/banking/common/ListData';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import ShimmerPlaceholder from 'react-native-shimmer-placeholder';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';


function CustomerNotes(props) {
  const session = useSessionToken();
  const textInputRef = useRef();
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    notesList: [],
    visible: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
  }, [session,data]);

  const getNotes = async () => {
    try {
      const qs = require('qs');
      let params = qs.stringify({
        cust_id: props.customerId,
        operation: 'notes_list',
      });
      await axios
        .post(
          'https://abc.cdhgfhg.com/adghagsa',
          params,
          {
            headers: {
              Cookie: session?.token,
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
          },
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.status === 1) {
            console.log('customernotes', response.data.data.hits.hits);
            setData({
              ...data,
              notesList: response.data.data.hits.hits,
              visible: false,
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('CustomerNoteserror', error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('CustomerNoteserror', error);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    var initialtv = Number(index + 1).toString();
    var formattedDate = moment(item._source.added_on).format(
      'ddd, MMM DD YYYY',
    );
    // console.log('initial', item, initialtv);
    const data = {
      text: item._source.notes,
      mobile: formattedDate,
      amount: '',
    };

    return <ListData item={data} />;
  };

  const handleInputSubmit = useCallback(ev => {
    const input = ev.nativeEvent.text;
    // validate all you want here
    setNotes(input);
  }, []);

  const submitNotes = () => {
    if (notes.length > 0) {
      setData(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        visible: true,
      }));
      addNotes();
    } else {
      Toast.show('Enter Notes');
    }
  };

  const addNotes = async () => {
    try {
      const qs = require('qs');
      let params = qs.stringify({
        cust_id: props.customerId,
        operation: 'add_notes',
        notes: notes,
      });
     
      await axios
        .post(
          'https://abc.cdhgfhg.com/adghagsa',
          params,
          {
            headers: {
              Cookie: session?.token,
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
          },
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.status === 1) {
            // console.log('addNotes', response.data);
           getNotes();
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('addNoteserror', error);
         
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('CustomerNoteserror', error);
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      {data.visible == true ? (
        <ActivityIndicator
          size="large"
          color="#0096FF"
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
      {data.notesList.length != 0 ? (
        <FlatList
          data={data.notesList}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          style={{marginTop: hp('1.5%')}}
        />
      ) : (
        <Nodata />
      )}

      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          marginBottom: '4%',
        }}>
        <TextInput
          ref={textInputRef}
          autoFocus={false}
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          placeholder="Write something"
          placeholderTextColor={'#D0D0D0'}
          onChangeText={
            text => setNotes(text)
            // (data.notes = text)
          }
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => submitNotes()}
          style={{
            height: 44,
            width: 46,
            backgroundColor: '#0096FF',
            borderRadius: 6,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            elevation: 5,
            marginRight: '4%',
          }}>
          <Icon
            name={'send'}
            size={20}
            color="#ffffff"
            style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default React.memo(CustomerNotes);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  TextInputStyleClass: {
    height: 45,
    borderColor: '#0096FF',
    flex: 7,
    marginLeft: '4%',
    marginRight: '4%',
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 6,
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 12,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    fontSize: 14,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#000000',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
  },
  subTitle: {
    fontSize: 11,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    color: '#000000',
  },
});
```

I am fetching data from `getNotes()` API to render in Flatlist also I have a textinput at the bottom of the page. Whenever I submit textinput data to addNotes API data is added sucessfully and again I am calling getNotes API to reload the data in flatlist.

The issue is data rendering in flatlist is getting very slow and also the activityIndicator is not loading properly. When I call submitNotes the activityIndicator should start loading once the data is added and finished data rendering in flatlist the activityloader should stop loading.

Answer (score 0):

To reload the flatlist each time the data changes you can pass [extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) props. For performance optimizations, you can limit the number of items to be loaded at once using [initialNumToRender](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender), and onScroll more items will be loaded. Toggle [refreshing](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#refreshing) props to true/false based on API response.

```
<FlatList
  data={data.notesList}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  style={{marginTop: hp('1.5%')}}
  keyExtractor={...}
  extraData={data.noteList}
  initialNumToRender={10}  
  refreshing={true}         
/>
```

Comment: <FlatList
          data={data.notesList}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          style={{marginTop: hp('1.5%')}}
          initialNumToRender={10}           
          extraData={data.noteList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => (index.toString())}
        />

Comment: I have changed my flatlist but still loader is not showing properly.i want loader should visible at the center of page

Comment: @Vishali can you try adding refreshing={true} as well and see how it goes?

Comment: <FlatList
          data={data.notesList}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          style={{marginTop: hp('1.5%')}}
          initialNumToRender={10}           
          extraData={data.noteList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => (index.toString())}
          refreshing={true}
        />

Comment: changed a code like above.but still having issue with activityIndicator